# Artillery.IO Logging and Debugging

Tags: load, artillery

I'm trying out Artillery.io (http://artillery.io) as a load and performance tool, but I can't seem to get the debugging working.

I'm seeing the output and reports get generated, but for certain HTTP responses (404/401/500.x) I want to see the packets sent and responses received retrospectively.

The documentation at https://artillery.io/docs/debugging.html#logging-everything says that I can run

```
set DEBUG=http,http:capture,http:response
```

and then launch my script using the run command (I'm on Windows).

This makes no difference at all, there is no tracing of packets sent/received in either the console or the generated report.

Anyone know how to get artillery to trace out what its doing, request by request and response? Preferably added to the report file, but I'll take console alone if I have to.

Comment: Hi there, it's been a year and a half since this question was asked, but i started facing this problem(i'm on Windows as well). Could you describe steps you have performed in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi Kyle - In my case I was attempting to run this from PowerShell. If I run from a normal CMD prompt terminal on windows or Terminal on Mac/Nix it works fine. These settings are environment variables, so if you have to use PowerShell the comment from Peng Tuck Kwok  in the solution below will work as well.

Comment: Looks like the debugging.html page has been replaced. New link is  https://artillery.io/docs/examples/#debugging-http-tests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was running this from a powershell console. Dropped down to good old CMD and it works as documented.

Comment: If you are in PowerShell you could do this: $Env:DEBUG="DEBUG=http,http:capture,http:response"

Answer (score 4):

Tested on **Windows** in **Git Bash** terminal.

## Setting debug:

```
 export DEBUG=http,http:capture,http:response
```

Testing:

```
 echo $DEBUG
```

## Running script for tests

### For **Artillery v2**

Create file **script.yml**:

```
config:
  target: "https://httpbin.org/"
  phases:
    - duration: 3
      arrivalRate: 1
scenarios:
  - name: "Get"
    flow:
      - get:
          url: "/get"
```

run it:  `artillery run script.yml`

### For **Artillery v1** see [docs](https://www.artillery.io/docs/guides/guides/command-line#quick).

```
artillery quick -c 1 -n 1 https://httpbin.org/get
```

## Debug response:

```
Started phase 0, duration: 1s @ 16:20:02(+0200) 2021-05-11
/   http request: {
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "user-agent": "Artillery (https://artillery.io)"
  }
} +0ms
  http:response {
  http:response   "date": "Tue, 11 May 2021 14:20:03 GMT",
  http:response   "content-type": "application/json",
  http:response   "content-length": "254",
  http:response   "connection": "keep-alive",
  http:response   "server": "gunicorn/19.9.0",
  http:response   "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
  http:response   "access-control-allow-credentials": "true"
  http:response } +1ms
  http:response "{\n  \"args\": {}, \n  \"headers\": {\n    \"Host\": \"httpbin.org\", \n    \"User-Agent\": \"Artillery (https://artillery.io)\", \n    \"X-Amzn-Trace-Id\": \"Root=1-609a9293-031b2371069a353d0cbb4131\"\n  }, \n  \"origin\": \"213.76.55.123\", \n  \"url\": \"https://httpbin.org/get\"\n}\n" +1ms
Report @ 16:20:04(+0200) 2021-05-11
```

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell you would have to set the environment variable DEBUG to eg http like this:

```
$Env:DEBUG = "http"
```

You can check the current value as follows:

```
$Env:DEBUG
```

See Powershell docs on [Using and changing environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.1#using-and-changing-environment-variables).

Answer (score -1):

Update: looks like http debugging was changed. See https://artillery.io/docs/examples/#debugging-http-tests for the revised debugging documentation.

Comment: Link 404's for me